# Problem Changing KDevelop Color Scheme

Tags: kde, kdevelop

While trying to customize my color scheme in KDevelop, even after setting all the standard colors, as well as setting all colors for the modes I use, it keeps using a bunch of colors in the schema I have not set, and I cannot find where these colors are being set. For example, all my variable names are yellow, and I have not set any color coding to be yellow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is driving me nuts. Thank you.

Comment: Is Semantic Code Highlighting enabled?